# PayFlow sandbox integration issue

Tags: paypal

Paypal forced us to use payflow service which I believe uses their classic API. I need to make this payflow work on sandbox mode asap.

In these [guide](http://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929) on part III number 4 instruction, it says that I need to put my sandbox email account on the sandbox email address field under PayPal Express Checkout. The problem is there is no PayPal Express Checkout on the page. Any idea?[image: image here]

Comment: You could just use PayFlow to process credit cards and then use the regular SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment APIs to handle Express Checkout on your site.  That would make the sandbox work for you very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a PayPal Sandbox account to be used in the PayPal manager, PayPal services need to be activate on the PayFlow account which they are often not on test PayFlow accounts.   If the field is missing form the Set Up page it is  because these services are not active on your test account.   I would recommend contacting PayPal Customer Support to get assistance with this function on your test account.